# Jquery grep with two arrays

Tags: jquery

I have got this code

```
var Movies = [
    'Alice in Wonderland', 
    'Above Suspicion', 
    'A Christmas Story', 
    'A Crack in the Floor', 
    'A Deadly Encounter '
];
var imgNames = [
    '../img/ma.jpg', 
    '../img/mt', 
    '../img/mtt',
    '../img/mf', 
    '../img/mff'
];
var results = $.grep(Movies.slice(0, 10)function(item){
    return item.search(RegExp(query, "i")) != -1;
});
```

I want in .grep two arrays not one when i tried to write

```
Movies.slice(0, 10),imgNames.slice(0, 10),
```

It stopped working

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @Nirnae To show images with the names of movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I would create an object:

```
var Movies = {
    "Alice in Wonderland":'../img/ma.jpg', 
    "Above Suspicion":'../img/mt', 
    "A Christmas Story":'../img/mtt', 
    "A Crack in the Floor":'../img/mf', 
    "A Deadly Encounter":'../img/mff'
}
```

The you can just match the case on the Index, and you can use the same Value. You can do similar with `$.grep()`:

```
var Movies = [
    'Alice in Wonderland', 
    'Above Suspicion', 
    'A Christmas Story', 
    'A Crack in the Floor', 
    'A Deadly Encounter '
];
var imgNames = [
    '../img/ma.jpg', 
    '../img/mt', 
    '../img/mtt',
    '../img/mf', 
    '../img/mff'
];
var results = $.grep(Movies.slice(0, 10), function(item, index){
    if(item.search(RegExp(query, "i")) != -1){
        return [ Movies[index], imgNames[index] ];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```